# Градиент у border

Tags: html, css

Можно ли как-то применить градиент к `border`?

Желательно что-нибудь попроще, если такое конечно есть...

Comment: А разве border-color не работает с градиентом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот один из вариантов:

```css
div {
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    -webkit-border-image: 
      -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(black), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))) 1 100%;
    -webkit-border-image: 
      -webkit-linear-gradient(black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
    -moz-border-image:
      -moz-linear-gradient(black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;    
    -o-border-image:
      -o-linear-gradient(black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
    border-image:
      linear-gradient(to bottom, black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background: #eee"></div>
```

взято из [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/)

Там много альтернатив.

Comment: Видел этот вариант... Но я слышал, что он не работает при border-radius.